# How to integrate Paypal Standard Checkout in PHP? Paypal popup appears and disappears

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway

**Modified Code**

I am referring https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ to integrate Paypal standard checkout with my PHP website. I am trying to convert that node js code in PHP. Below is what I have written but when I click on the Paypal button, the paypal popup appears and disappears.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=a"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

  <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return fetch('create-paypal-order', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            amount: '10.00'
          })
        }).then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        }).then(function(order) {
          return order.id;
        });
      },
      onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return fetch('capture-paypal-order', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            orderID: data.orderID
          })
        }).then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        }).then(function(details) {
          alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
          // TODO: Perform any necessary post-payment actions
        });
      },
      onError: function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        // TODO: Handle errors gracefully
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**create-paypal-order.php**

```
<?php
$clientId = 'a';
$clientSecret = 'b';

$amount = 10.00; 
$currency = 'USD'; 

$authString = base64_encode($clientId . ':' . $clientSecret);

$apiUrl = 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';

$apiHeaders = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Language: en_US',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $authString
);

$apiData = 'grant_type=client_credentials';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $apiHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $apiData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/lib/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false) 
{
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

$accessToken = json_decode($response, true)['access_token'];

$apiUrl = 'https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders';
$apiHeaders = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken
);
$apiData = json_encode(array(
    'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
    'purchase_units' => array(
        array(
            'amount' => array(
                'currency_code' => $currency,
                'value' => $amount
            )
        )
    )
));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $apiHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $apiData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/lib/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

$order = json_decode($response, true);

echo $order['id'];

?>
```

**capture-paypal-order.php**

```
<?php
$clientID = 'a';
$secret = 'b';

$orderID = $_POST['orderID'];

$authString = base64_encode($clientId . ':' . $clientSecret);
$apiUrl = 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';
$apiHeaders = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Language: en_US',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $authString
);
$apiData = 'grant_type=client_credentials';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $apiHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $apiData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/lib/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

$accessToken = json_decode($response, true)['access_token'];

$apiUrl = "https://api.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/$orderID/capture";
$apiHeaders = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $apiHeaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/lib/cacert.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
if ($response === false) {
    die(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

$orderData = json_decode($response, true);

echo json_encode($orderData);
?>
```

Comment: So what does the `err` you are logging to console contain?

Comment: Why are you so arbitrarily switching between curl and file_get_contents, to make API requests? The latter, at least the way you are currently using it, will not even get you the response body in case of an error on the HTTP level - but inside the body is the most likely place to find any _explanation_ for what error might have happened.

Comment: _"Is there any PHP equivalent documentation available which I can use directly?"_ - they offer a Postman collection of the common API calls, and Postman can create _code_ for you in multiple languages, among them PHP.

Comment: @CBroe - how to use Postman?

Comment: Install Postman, import there collection, and then https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: @CBroe - I have modified the code.

Comment: Can't tell you what is going on by just looking at the code. Do you get anything from the `console.error(err)` from the `onError` in the client-side code? Have you checked how the requests this causes actually get answered, in the browser dev tools network panel?